# Dummy argument associated actual procedure differs from dummy argument of the dummy procedure

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm using a the function [NEQNF](https://docs.roguewave.com/imsl/fortran/6.0/math/neqnf.htm) from the IMSL Fortran Library to solve a non-linear equation system and get 3 errors. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on a x64 system. The error says the following:

```
Error #7061: The characterístic of dummy argument 1 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 1 of the dummy procedure [FCN_SS]


Error #7062: The characterístic of dummy argument 2 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 2 of the dummy procedure [FCN_SS]

Error #7063: The characterístic of dummy argument 3 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 3 of the dummy procedure [FCN_SS]
```

The code is:

```
    include 'link_fnl_shared.h' 

    use neqnf_int
    use umach_int

    implicit none

!Declaring variables
    .
    .
    .

    Contains

    subroutine solve_ss(x, fnorm)

        integer n
        parameter (n=2)

        integer k, nout
        real(dp) :: fnorm, x(n), xguess(n)

        data xguess/1.0_dp, 0.3_dp/   !guess for total output in units

        call umach (2, nout)
        call neqnf (fcn_ss, x, xguess=xguess, fnorm=fnorm)

    end subroutine solve_ss


    subroutine fcn_ss(x, f, n)

        implicit none

        !specification
        integer n
        real(dp) :: x(n), f(n)

    .
    .
    .

    F(1)=...

    F(2)=...

    end subroutine fcn_ss
```

I'm not sure what the error is about, since the declaration of the variables is the same in `solve_ss` and `fcn_ss`.

Comment: Try calling `D_NEQNF` instead of `NEQNF` (eventually also `DNEQNF`). Preferably, make a compilable [mcve].

Comment: You have the source to module neqnf_int in the IMSL include folder. I no longer have access to this, but it's NUMERICAL_LIBRARIES_F90.f90 or something like that. Open it in a text editor (or Visual Studio) and find the declaration of NEQNF and its specifics and compare to your FCN_SS.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the library explicitly states ([here](https://docs.roguewave.com/imsl/fortran/6.0/math/programmingtips.htm) and [here](https://docs.roguewave.com/imsl/fortran/6.0/math/moduleusage.htm)) that you are required to `use` the respective modules in order to have access to modern implementation of the routines.

Otherwise, you may be (I can't test, but I'm basing on [this](https://docs.roguewave.com/imsl/fortran/6.0/math/usinglibrarysubprograms.htm)) accessing legacy support of the library. So, instead of the generic Fortran 90 interface, It may be leading you to the FORTRAN77 specific interface:

```
NEQNF (FCN, ERRREL, N, ITMAX, XGUESS, X, FNORM)
```

Other detail is that the documentation explicity states you must declare the passed function as external:

```
external fcn_ss
```

Still, I'm not sure about those guesses. Could be that or any other strange error. Please provide feedback.

Comment: I'm not sure, actually. I just noted it is stated by the documentation but not followed in the calling. I'm still trying to find the source o the function in the web to compare the declarations. Should it be better converted into a comment?

Comment: Well, I think between us we've confused anyone who looks at the edits...

Comment: It appears to me the OP does use some module with NEQNF in name. I think the NEQNF_INT supplies the interface. At least the name suggests that.

Comment: Sorry, guys. I misread the question and thought OP was including the routines instead of using the modules, so I wrote that edit. But then I realized he indeed used, so that edit doesn't make sense anymore; that's why I rolled it back

Comment: I don't know the answer, so please choose the version which best suits your thinking.  My edit was based on one of yours, but there was a bit of a conflict on the one I chose: it wasn't deliberately picking one over the other.

Comment: See my comment in the OP. NEQNF_INT is indeed a module supplied with IMSL that has the generic interface for NEQNF. The source is also included (all the _INT modules come from the one big .f90 source.)